# Entity Framework unique on child class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am confused about how this kind of situation should be handled in Entity Framework.

I have a character base class:

```
public class Character
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Realm Realm { get; set; }
    public Guid RealmId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Character has name and is bound to realm.

Character controlled by a player is definitely a character. It is bound to a player/user:

```
public class PlayerCharacter : Character
{        
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

NPC is also a character: it does not need to have any properties for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
public class Npc : Character { }
```

Now, obviously, you would not want to have to characters on the same realm with the same name, but you can have as many `Orcs` as you need on a single realm, so we would need to define unique constraint on `PlayerCharacter`, for example via `.HasAlternateKey`:

```
public DbSet<PlayerCharacter> Characters { get; set; }
public DbSet<Npc> Npcs { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerCharacter>()
        .HasAlternateKey("Name", "RealmId");
}
```

Now we add migration:

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add 5
System.InvalidOperationException: A key cannot be configured on 
'PlayerCharacter' because it is a derived type. The key must be 
configured on the root type 'Character'.
```

Ok, how about a unique index?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerCharacter>()
    .HasIndex("Name", "RealmId")
    .IsUnique();

$ dotnet ef migrations add 5
Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'
```

It worked! But wait:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Character",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
        Discriminator = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        RealmId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
        // other props...
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Character", x => x.Id);
        // foreign keys...
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Character_Name_RealmId",
    table: "Character",
    columns: new[] { "Name", "RealmId" },
    unique: true);
```

Now both player characters and npcs are unique by name! How can I set unique only in derived class?

Comment: You are setting up TPH, right?

Comment: @IvanStoev, what is TPH?

Comment: [Table Per Hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance) inheritance strategy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way you can do it currently (EF Core 2.0.1) is to use filtered unique index based on [*Discriminator* column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance) value.

Unfortunately the [`HasFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalindexbuilderextensions.hasfilter?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalIndexBuilderExtensions_HasFilter_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_IndexBuilder_System_String_) fluent API is not db agnostic. Here is the configuration for SqlServer:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerCharacter>()
    .HasIndex("Name", "RealmId")
    .IsUnique()
    .HasFilter($"Discriminator = '{nameof(PlayerCharacter)}'"); // <--
```

Comment: Is Pgsql supported?

Comment: Can't test, but according to the [PostgeSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html), database supports it through `WHERE predicate` clause of the `CREATE INDEX`, so there should not be a problem the EFC Pgsql provider to support it.